# How to bind F1 to F12 keys to mousewheel up and down in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

For a game, i want to bind the F1 to F12 keys to my mousewheel so i can scroll through them. For example: Scrolling up should give the result of sending F1 then F2 then F3 and so on while mousewheeldown will send the last F(i) - 1.
In Pseudocode:

```
i = 1
Mousewheelup::
if(i < 12):
  Send F(i+1)
  i++
else:
  i = 1
  Send F(i)

Mousewheeldown::
if(i > 0):
  Send F(i-1)
  i--
else:
  i = 12
  Send F(i)
```

something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
i := 0
WheelUp::
if(i < 12)
{ 
  Fn := "F" i+1  
  Send, {%Fn%}
  i++
}
else
{
  i := 1
  Fn := "F" i
  Send, {%Fn%}
}



WheelDown::
if(i > 1)
{
  Fn := "F" i-1  
  Send, {%Fn%}
  i--
}
else
{
  i := 12
  Fn := "F" i
  Send, {%Fn%}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunenately it doesnt work ingame (Diablo 2) and im not sure if it keeps sending the same F hotkey instead of all